# how to solve [vue-hooks] Not found vue instance in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I try to run [this code in codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-bush-mepje?file=/src/main.js), but I got an error - its happens when I click on the links:

> [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: [vue-hooks] Not found

> vue instance." ReferenceError: [vue-hooks] Not found vue instance.

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "product" is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Not sure why cause it seems like the code is correct.

I try to remove some pieces from my code and seems like `useRouter` is the problem. but why? any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Vue to use hooks.

```
import hooks from "@u3u/vue-hooks";
Vue.use(hooks)

import { useRouter } from "@u3u/vue-hooks"
```